# Proof for estimation lemma

Tags: real-analysis

Revising my lecture notes for real analysis - I got stuck with this proof, more specifically I don't really understand where statement (15) comes from.

Any help much appreciated!

[image: proof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x>0$. If $Kx^{n-1}\leq\dfrac{a_nx^n}{2}$, we can multiply both sides by $\dfrac{2}{x^{n-1}a_n}$, and obtain $\dfrac{2K}{a_n}\leq x$. For the other implication, multiply both sides by $\dfrac{x^{n-1}a_n}{2}$.